# Can't find Class with Class.forName() but it exists

Tags: java, reflection, classloader, urlclassloader

I have a program in which I am generating classes at runtime (included only variable and associated getters and setters methods). Later I want to fill the classes.

To get the class - I know its Name, but its not in the classpath - I tried .forName() but I always get a ClassNotFoundException.

Here is my example:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.wam.business.wsobjects.Testclass
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at gui.Application.main(Application.java:94)
```

And the code:

```
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    DynamicURLClassLoader dynamicURLClassLoader = new DynamicURLClassLoader(urlClassLoader);
    dynamicURLClassLoader.addURL(new URL("file://C:\\dev\\Eclipse_was\\guitest\\generated"));

    Class c = Class.forName("com.test.wam.business.wsobjects.Testclass");

    Object classInstance = c.newInstance();
```

The ClassLoader:

```
public class DynamicURLClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

public DynamicURLClassLoader(URLClassLoader classLoader) {
    super(classLoader.getURLs());
}

@Override
public void addURL(URL url) {
    super.addURL(url);
}
```

}

The full qualified Name to the file (created with eclipse -> copy full qualified Name)

> /guitest/generated/com/test/wam/business/wsobjects/Testclass.java

What is wrong here?

Comment: "but its not in the classpath". That.

Comment: `Class.forName`   need `class` files , `Testclass.java`  is not .

Comment: what can I do in this case - I only have the generated java files and no class Files?

Comment: Just creating that `DynamicURLClassLoader` does nothing, `Class.forName(...)` is not somehow automatically going to use that classloader. And ofcourse the Java source must first be compiled.

Comment: I added the code for the DynamicURLClassLoader in the question

Answer (score 3):

I can see two problems:

1) You are creating a `DynamicURLClassLoader` and adding the URL to it, but you are not actually using it.  This statement:

```
 Class c = Class.forName("com.test.wam.business.wsobjects.Testclass");
```

will use the classloader that loaded the current class.  That is probably the application's default classloader, but it is certainly NOT the classloader you just created.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-) says:

> [`Class.forName(className)`] returns the `Class` object associated with the class or interface with the given string name. Invoking this method is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> Class.forName(className, true, currentLoader)
> ```
>
> where `currentLoader` denotes the defining class loader of the current class.

So .... the solution is:

```
Class c = Class.forName("com.test.wam.business.wsobjects.Testclass",
                        true, dynamicURLClassLoader);
```

2) This string:

```
"file://C:\\dev\\Eclipse_was\\guitest\\generated"
```

is not a valid "file:" URL.  The correct URL for the path you are trying to reference would be:

```
"file:///C:/dev/Eclipse_was/guitest/generated"
```

The way that you wrote the URL *might* work, but it is not the correct way to do it.

Reference:

- [File URIs in Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/)

Answer (score 2):

The method [`Class.forName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-) uses the `ClassLoader` of the caller class, if you want to use a specific `ClassLoader` to load your class you need to use [`Class.forName(String name, boolean initialize, ClassLoader loader)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-boolean-java.lang.ClassLoader-) instead as next:

```
Class c = Class.forName(
    "com.test.wam.business.wsobjects.Testclass", true, dynamicURLClassLoader
);
```

**NB:** This will work if and only if the `URL` that you provide to your `DynamicURLClassLoader` is valid and is the path to the parent folder in which you have your class